# Pandas - Problem reading a datetime64 object from a json file

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to save a Pandas data frame as a JSON file.  One of the columns has the type datetime64[ns].  When I print the column the correct date is displayed.  However, when I save it as a JSON file and read it back later the date value changes even after I change the column type back to datetime64[ns].  Here is a sample app which shows the issue I am running into:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
  
import json
import pandas as pd

s = pd.Series(['1/1/2000'])
in_df = pd.DataFrame(s)
in_df[0] = pd.to_datetime(in_df[0], format='%m/%d/%Y')
print("in_df\n")
print(in_df)
print("\nin_df dtypes\n")
print(in_df.dtypes)
in_df.to_json("test.json")

out_df = pd.read_json("test.json")
out_df[0] = out_df[0].astype('datetime64[ns]')
print("\nout_df\n")
print(out_df)
print("\nout_df dtypes\n")
print(out_df.dtypes)
```

Here is the output:

```
in_df

           0
0 2000-01-01

in_df dtypes

0    datetime64[ns]
dtype: object

out_df

                           0
0 1970-01-01 00:15:46.684800  <--- Why don't I get 2000-1-1 here?

out_df dtypes

0    datetime64[ns]
dtype: object
```

I'm expecting the get the original date displayed (2000-1-1) when I read back the JSON file.  What am I doing wrong with my conversion?  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df = pd.read_json("test.json")
df[0] = pd.to_datetime(df[0], unit='ms')
print("\ndf\n")
print(df)
print("\ndf dtypes\n")
print(df.dtypes)
```

will give you

```
df

           0
0 2000-01-01

df dtypes

0    datetime64[ns]
dtype: object
```

This should work for all millisecond json columns you need